# map GeoPandas dataframe with folium no results

Tags: geopandas, folium

I am trying to display on a folium map a set of polygons from a geodataframe. The code returns no errors but the polygons do not appear.
I have checked the projections ('epsg:3857') and the coordinates in the geo-json seem to be ok.
the code used is as follows:

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location = [22, 55], tiles='cartodbpositron' , zoom_start = 5)

draft = hot_spots_draft
draft.crs = {'init' : 'epsg:3857'}


for _, r in draft.iterrows():
    #without simplifying the representation of each borough, the map might not be displayed
    #sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry'])
    sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry']).simplify(tolerance=0.001)
    geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
    #print(geo_j)
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                           style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'})
    folium.Popup(r['ID']).add_to(geo_j)
    geo_j.add_to(map)
map
```

To test the geodataframe I used the code below and I got a simple plot

```
hot_spots_draft.plot(figsize=(10, 50), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
```

I also exported the geodataframe to a shapefile with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `draft.crs = {'init' : 'epsg:3857'}`
It does not transform the coordinates of your polygon. Simply sets the crs.
Instead you need to explicitly transform coordinates of your polygon using  pyproj Transformer.transform function to convert the projected coordinate system or better use `to_crs` function of geopandas as shown.

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location = [lat, long], tiles='cartodbpositron' , zoom_start = 5)

draft = hot_spots_draft

for _, r in draft.iterrows():
    sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry'])
    sim_geo.set_crs(epsg="original_epsg_of_shapefile", inplace=True)
    sim_geo = sim_geo.to_crs("EPSG:4326") # convert to epsg 4326 to display on map and not 3857
#     sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry']).simplify(tolerance=0.001) #req only if you have multipolygon
    geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j, style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'})
#     folium.Popup(r['ID']).add_to(geo_j)
    geo_j.add_to(map)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works!!